# Function to filter JSON Object Javascript/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of JSON Objects like this:

```
[{ 
  id: "1"
  times:{ 
          start: '2018-05-09T06:05:28.144Z',
          end: '2018-05-09T06:10:21.564Z' 
       },
},

{ 
  id: "2"
  times:{ 
          start: '2018-06-09T06:10:25.144Z',
          end: '2018-06-09T06:20:20.564Z' 
       },
}]
```

I want to write a function say that will return only the objects that the total minutes between "start" and "end" timestamps are in a specific range.

example: return all objects that the total minutes between "start" and "end" timestamps is in the range 3 to 5 minutes.

Thanks in advance for your Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be it :

```js
var timeArray = [{
    id: "1",
    times: {
      start: '2018-05-09T06:06:21.564Z',
      end: '2018-05-09T06:10:21.564Z'
    }
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    times: {
      start: '2018-06-09T06:10:25.144Z',
      end: '2018-06-09T06:20:20.564Z'
    }
  }
]

function inRange(arr) {
  const max = 5   // 5 minutes
  const min = 3   // 3 minutes
  const filteredArray = arr.filter((obj) => {
  const range = (new Date(obj.times.end) - new Date(obj.times.start)) / 60000 // in minutes
   return range > min && range < max ? obj : ''
  })
  return filteredArray
}


console.log(inRange(timeArray))
```